# How to test internet application at local computer (windows-7)?

Tags: c++, windows, testing, boost, virtual-machine

This application sends data periodically to a server. What I need to do is setup a testing environment on the local developing machine so that I can check the correct packets are being sent in each situation. I thought a good approach would be a server VM set up on the local computer which would receive the packets and respond just like the real thing, but the problem is how do I route the packets of an application running on windows to a VM machine. I don't want to modify my application code. I just want to have windows pass on the packets it receives from the application to the VM or otherwise another application that will do the testing. Is this possible? If not, please let me know about any other solution(s) to this problem.

Comment: Since you're explicitly not modifying your application code, this isn't a programming question per-se.  You should consider posting this sort of thing on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running a decent VM you should be able to give it an IP address visible from the host, and configure it so that you can run web servers on it, ssh to it, etc.

Look at the networking features of your VM.  Or find a tutorial on how to do this, such as this one for VirtualBox:

http://www.tolaris.com/2009/03/05/using-host-networking-and-nat-with-virtualbox/

Answer (score 0):

Well it's some kind of a hack but you can use `ARP Poisoning` (man in the middle attack) to sniff packets. There is a tool named `Cain & Abel` which can do this for you. I've used this tool to sniff packets between two non-pc machines. Use at your own risk and if your anti-virus tool alerts, know that the tool has no virus but what it does is detected as one.

Edit: Please note that my approach doesn't require a VM server.